# ReloadableConfiguration getProperty returns null instead of map when reading from JSON property file

Tags: java, properties-file

I need to have a ReloadableConfiguration that handles JSON files to read properties from a property file. Everything I tried, works fine for String or List but does not work for Map. It just returns null instead of a `Map<String, String>` object (or anything else) (see the value of "foo" in the example test case below).

The following test case summarizes everything that is implemented so far. The return value of `configuration.getProperty("foo")` is null. I also tried to use `getCollection` instead of `getProperty` and some other of the functions but it also fails in retrieving a map:

```
    @Test
    void testJsonConfigLoading() throws IOException {
        // Create property file
        Path configurationFile = Files.createTempFile("json-test-foo", ".properties");
        String TEST_FILE_DIR = "my.test.dir";
        System.setProperty(TEST_FILE_DIR, configurationFile.getParent().toString());
        String prop = "{\"bla\": \"blubb\", \"foo\": {\"k1\": \"A\", \"k2\": \"B\"}}";
        Files.write(configurationFile, prop.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.WRITE);

        // Create property reader
        Parameters params = new Parameters();
        ReloadingFileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration> builder = 
                new ReloadingFileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration>(JSONConfiguration.class)
                .configure(
                        params
                                .fileBased()
                                .setFile(configurationFile.toFile())
                );
        ImmutableConfiguration configuration = new ReloadableConfiguration(builder);

        // test simple string
        String bla = configuration.getString("bla");
        assertEquals("blubb", bla);

        // test map
        Object property = configuration.getProperty("foo");
        assertNotNull(property); // <= here the test case fails since property is null
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(property);
        Map<String, String> foo = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
        Map<String, String> map1 = Stream.of(new String[][] {
                { "k1", "A" },
                { "k2", "B" },
        }).collect(Collectors.toMap(data -> data[0], data -> data[1]));
        assertEquals(map1, foo);
    }
```

I tried different configuration parameters for the ConfigurationBuilder and different method to get something back from the configuration. But the return value of `configuration.getProperty("foo")` (or other getters) still remains null and not the expected `Map<String, String>`.

Yes, of course, I searched / read the user guide at https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/user_guide.html but did not find anything that helped me further on. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it to work with following lines of code:

```
ImmutableConfiguration subset = configuration.immutableSubset("foo");
assertNotNull(subset);
Iterator<String> keysIterator = subset.getKeys();
Map<String, String> propertyMap = stream(
            Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(keysIterator, Spliterator.ORDERED), false)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), s -> subset.getString(s)));
Map<String, String> map1 = Stream.of(new String[][] {
            { "k1", "A" },
            { "k2", "B" },
    }).collect(Collectors.toMap(data -> data[0], data -> data[1]));
assertEquals(map1, propertyMap);
```